# Deleting user profiles on a remote windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, user-profile, remote-access

Is it possible to remotely delete a user profile on a Windows 7 machine, using something like mmc?

(and I mean where you delete the registry entries too not just the folder)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself [`delprof2`](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/).  It has other neat features for cleaning up profiles.  The following would delete the profile for user "jscott" on the computer "wkst-01"

```
delprof2 /c:wkst-01 /id:jscott /u
```